# How to convert minute to hour and in 24hrs format in mysql

Tags: mysql

In one of table's time is stored in minutes

870 minutes when we convert in excel we use formula like minutes/1440 converter in time format

so how can I do it in MySQL? I tried

```
sec_to_time(870*60)
```

with out using above formula how can we convert minute to hour and 24 hrs formats

Comment: What's wrong with `sec_to_time(870*60)`?

Comment: i tried this query SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(1715*60) and output is 28:35:00 but correct time is 02:35:00

Comment: 2:35? Isn't that 4:35?

Comment: sorry it is 4:35 your correct

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(1715*60,86400));
```